# Value assignment via boolean index in one dataframe changes values in a different dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am not sure what I am missing... Why does `data` change when I am manipulating `data_pos` and `data_neg`? I am running 3.8.5.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> data = pd.DataFrame(data={'A':[-3,-2,-1,0,0,1,2,3]})
>>> print(data)
   A
0 -3
1 -2
2 -1
3  0
4  0
5  1
6  2
7  3
>>> data_pos = data
>>> data_neg = data
>>>
>>> data_pos.loc[data_pos.loc[:,'A']<0,'A']=0
>>> data_neg.loc[data_neg.loc[:,'A']>0,'A']=0
>>>
>>> print(data)
   A
0  0
1  0
2  0
3  0
4  0
5  0
6  0
7  0
>>>
```

Comment: Obligatory link to  [Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: Yes thank you, I just hope my ignorance of this fact hasn't burned me in the past without me knowing it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `copy`

```
data_pos = data.copy()

data_neg = data.copy()
```